# Avoid losing resources on waking up netty

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, netty, wakeup

I want to avoid spending a lot of CPU resources on waking up netty's thread. Every time the packet is flushed, the netty is wakened up. When I have a lot of packet sending I have a lot of these wake-ups, which is really hard for the CPU to process. How to make it spend less time on waking up, I found something like SelectStrategy.BUSY_WAIT, but as soon as I pick this option, my CPU is at 20% at all times.
Is there a way to do something like delayed sleep/awaiting for wakeup?

I also tried to merge EventLoops of channels, but it seems that every channel has its own EventLoop.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `EventLoop`s and these are shared between `Channel`s. How many of these are used is depending on how netty is configured and how the `Channel`s are bootstrapped.

Regarding the wakups you might be able to reduce the overhead by do one of these:

- Only `flush` from within the `EventLoop`.
- Call `write` multiple times before call `flush` if you need to do it from outside the `EventLoop`.
- Pack multiple messages into one "object" pass it to `writeAndFlush(...)` and have your own `ChannelOutboundHandler` that "decompose" this object into messages.

Comment: Writing outside of the EventLoop seems to be using a lot of resources too, do you have something in mind other than packing packets into 1 object? I will consider this option of too course.

Comment: nope... writing from outside is a lot more expensive

Comment: I wouldn't say "a lot", in the profilers it's pretty similar, I will check if it's less expensive to call outside of the eventloop.

Comment: But you say to pack messages, but the client will get packed messages or every packet 1 by 1? Do you have example or some decumentation of this implementation?